# How to display a message upon login to specific tty

Tags: linux, centos-6, tty, virtual-terminal

In /etc/securetty I commented out tty2 and tty3:

```
#tty2
#tty3
```

This succesfully disables root login for these two terminals for root.

But is it possible to display a message such as "root login is disabled in this terminal" if a login attempt is made?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current terminal with the `tty` command, so you can put something like this in the user's `.bash_profile` file:

```
if [ `tty` = "/dev/pts/0" ]
then
   echo "......."
fi
```

Comment: I think this file won't run at all since the login failed.

Comment: Then you can allow the login, and run that script with an "exit" at the end, but I don't know if it's completely safe

Comment: @arsane you are right its not working. but thanks for the hint golimar